# JavaScriptで計算した結果をHTMLに表示したいです

Tags: javascript, html5

**現象**
JavaScriptで適正体重（身長(m)の2乗×22で求める）を算出したいが、index.htmlから入力した身長(m)を入力しても何も起こらない。consoleにはエラーが出現する。

以下、実際に出現したconsoleのエラー
[image: consoleのエラー]

**期待値**
入力フォームに身長(m)を入力したら、適正体重が表示されること。

**再現手順**
下記のコードを実行する。

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>適正体重を身長(m)の2乗×22で求める</title>
</head>
<body>
    身長(m):<input type="number" step="0.01"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="送信" id="calculation"> 
    適正体重(kg):<p id="result"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="calculation.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`calculation.js`

```
'use strict';

var calclation=document.getElementById('caluclation');
calclation.addEventListener('submit', (e) =>{

  var eleHeight=document.getElementById("height");

  function calc() {
  var height=parseFloat(eleHeight.value);

  var heightSquared=Math.pow(height, 2);
  var appropriateWeight=heightSquared*22;
  };

  console.log(appropriateWeight);
  var result=appropriateWeight;
  result.innerHTML="appropriateWeight";
});
```

**補足**
入力する身長は「センチメートル」ではなく「メートル」です。

Comment: 諸々の不備がありすぎて何とも…ですが、一つだけ指摘すると、`submit` イベントは `form` 要素で発生します。 [HTMLFormElement: submit イベント - Web API | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) から: 「submit イベントは <form> 要素自身で発生するものであり、その中の <button> や <input type="submit"> で発生するものではないことに注意してください。」

Answer (score 1):

> var calclation=document.getElementById('caluclation');

`calculation`では？
スペルミスですね。